# How to change URL links that were made by WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog. All the post are currently in this convention:

```
http://www.myblog.com/blog/?p=1442
```

Now I'd like to change the URL of all posts like this one:

```
http://www.gomidjets.com/blog/this-is-my-post
```

While it's quite easy to apply it by changing the blog settings, the big problem is about the links I've placed
in many external website. I can't change them, and I'd like to map the old links to the new links somehow.
Do you know how to do it - if that's possible at all?
Do you have a better solution?

Thank you very much

Comment: Moving Wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress will map all old URL to new one, in case if you provided all URL in their original shape, such as http://example.com/?page_id=80

The answer is: you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Works indeed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for can be found in the admin panel.

In the admin panel (http://www.your-wordpress-site.com/wp-admin), go to Settings > Permalinks

Comment: Thanks but my real question is about the redirecting of old URL to new one. I have many links in external website in the old format, and I can't change them. I'm looking for a solution to redirect/map them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Login to the admin panel first,

go for the settings->Permalink Settings

Select the format you want.

If you want change the base url for only some posts then you can edit from database.

Comment: Thanks but my real question is about the redirecting of old URL to new one. I have many links in external website in the old format, and I can't change them. I'm looking for a solution to redirect/map them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Redirection wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) to redirect your old url to your new url.

Answer (score 1):

The URL's should resolve fine because the original URL you're using is the permalink one to my knowledge. If you're wanting end users to be redirected to this url, that's a bit harder.

That aside, I couldn't find any plugins that already did this. What you want to do is check the current URL against the wordpress function get_permalink() and if it doesn't match, redirect to the current permalink URL.